# What happens in the distant future of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, event-horizon, observable-universe

In the standard cosmological model LCDM the universe approaches the asymtotic deSitter state in the distant future. Is it correct to say that all light-sources situated on the ultimate lightcone of a hypothetical observer (which is its event horizon at Hubble sphere distance) have infinite redshift, except local ones which are gravitationally bound?

Comment: I think so, yes

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct to say that all light-sources situated on the ultimate lightcone of a hypothetical observer (which is its event horizon at Hubble sphere distance) have infinite redshift, except local ones which are gravitationally bound?

Yes, that is correct. This horizon is called "Cosmic Event Horizon"(CEH). CEH represents the most distant object which we can receive information as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

As $t \rightarrow \infty$ Hubble Sphere approaches to CEH. This implies that at $t \rightarrow \infty$ the redshift of the galaxies which are not gravitationally bound to us will approach $\infty$ ($z \rightarrow \infty$).

You can calculate the CEH by using

$$\chi_{ceh} = c\int_{a(t_0)}^{a(t_{end})} dt/a(t)$$
or

$$\chi_{ceh} = \frac{c}{H_0}\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{da}{a[\Omega_ma^{-1} + \Omega_{\Lambda}a^2]^{1/2}}$$

since $\dot{a} = H_0[\Omega_ma^{-1} + \Omega_{\Lambda}a^2]^{1/2}$ for flat universe.

If you take $(\Omega_m, \Omega_{\Lambda}) = (0.3, 0.7)$, you'll find that $\chi_{ceh}  = 1.14\frac{c}{H_0}$

So the objects at a comoving distance about $16 Gyr$ are the ones which we can communicate now. We will never be able to communicate the galaxies which are further than this distance.

[image]

https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a clear answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a clear answer. Well, more than a decade ago I studied Davis and Lineweaver's paper. This is an excellent tutorial. However, I spotted some mistakes in the text and I wrote to them, but they didn't agree on my findings. So may I ask for your opinion? The formulas (13) on p.16 and  (14) on p. 17 are not correct in my opinion: both should be multiplied by a factor (1+z), or R replaced by Ro. Also, in Fig 5 I calculated the SR curve to lie above the other curves.  R. Kail

Comment: @ReneKail I think you are right. It should be better if they put $R_0$ instead of $R$. I dont have much idea about the figure. I need to calculate it but I do not have time for that

Comment: @ReneKail https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0105 I found this article. You can look at equation 5 and 6